# Replacing all non-zero results with "1" to form presence/absence

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited table

```
  a b c
A 5 2 0
B 0 5 4
C 4 3 4
D 2 0 2
```

I want to change the non-zero values to "1", without changing the column or row names.

Desired output:

```
  a b c
A 1 1 0
B 0 1 1
C 1 1 1
D 1 0 1
```

To clarify, this is an example table. The letters are variables representing the column/row names - there may be hundreds of columns and rows. The non-zero values (given here as numbers) may not necessarily be numbers - they might the names of  people for example.

Comment: With the additional info that you have added about names of people etc. it becomes very important to know what the delimiter is between the columns.

Comment: What does it need to do with values like `000`, `0.0`, `-0`, `0x0`, `+0e20`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming strictly tab-delimited input:

```
$ cat data.in
        a       b       c
A       nancy   bilbo baggins   0
B       0       darcy   bender
C       phantom menace  Unix    !!
D       last row        0       the end

$ cat -t data.in
^Ia^Ib^Ic
A^Inancy^Ibilbo baggins^I0
B^I0^Idarcy^Ibender
C^Iphantom menace^IUnix^I!!
D^Ilast row^I0^Ithe end
```

An `awk` script to do the job:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "\t" }

NR != 1 {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i != "0") {
            $i = "1";
        }
    }
}

{ print }
```

Running it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data.in
        a       b       c
A       1       1       0
B       0       1       1
C       1       1       1
D       1       0       1
```

The script compares each field (column) with the single character `0` (except for the first field) and replaces everything that isn't exactly `0` with a `1`.  The output will be tab-delimited.

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '1!s/ [^ ]*[^ 0][^ ]*/ 1/g'
```

Would replace any sequence of non-space characters that contains at least one character other than `0` (and that follows a space) with `1` (except on the first line).

IOW, that would replace anything other than sequences of 0s and the first column and row with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that headers does not include numbers like your sample, the most easy way i can think of is this:

```
sed 's/[1-9]/1/g' file.txt
```

mind the range : 1 up to 9 , zero excluded.

```
$ echo "A 5 2 0" |sed 's/[1-9]/1/g'
A 1 1 0
```

This works If the numbers in columns is up to 9. If this is not the case and numbers can be 10 or more i have to revise.

According to OP latest clarification , since non zero entries can be names, etc this will NOT work.

Comment: you can in fact say `[2-9]`, since replacing 1 with 1 is not necessary :) Also, what if the numbers are 10 or bigger?

Comment: @fedorqui According to the question, it's not numbers at all...

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, I see. Then probably the OP should provide more representative sample data, so we get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

This only works in bash

```
bash$ paste <(cut -f1 file) <(cut -f2- file |
        sed -r '1b;        # if title line then skip to end
        s#\t#\n#g          # seperate line to multi-line
        s#.*[^0].*#1#Mg    # apply multi-line operation 
        s#\n#\t#g' )       # turn to one line

        a       b       c
A       1       1       0
B       0       1       1
C       1       1       1
D       1       0       1
```

Comment: Worth noting that this only works where process substitution is supported, e.g. `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good task for Python.

```
$ cat input.txt
    a   b   c
A   alpha   beta    0
B   0   gamma   zeta
C   alpha   phi omega
D   kappa   0   delta

$ ./replace_nonzero.py  < input.txt                                                                                      
a   b   c
A   1   1   0
B   0   1   1
C   1   1   1
D   1   0   1
```

And here's the `replace_nonzero.py` itself:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

for index,line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
   if index == 0 :
       print(line.strip())
       continue
   words = line.strip().split()
   print(words[0],end="\t")

   new_line = []
   for word in words[1:]:
      if word.isdigit() and int(word) == 0:
          new_line.append('0')
      else:
          new_line.append('1')
   print("\t".join(new_line))
```

The way this works is simple: we skip first line since it's special case, and break down all other lines into words, and examine those starting from position 1. The logic here works from the opposite assumption - if the word that we got is a digit and is zero, then we append a string '0' into new list (which is a list of words per each line), otherwise - we append string '1'. Finally we take the new list , and print it out, again - tab-delimited.